# Regex code for email address, and how to link it with my feedback form

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core, rasa-x

I want to link my feedback form's email address and Regex to validate the email address entered by an customer

Comment: Can you share some coding attempts?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is a `validate` method. Inside your FormAction class you can define a `validate_{slot_name}` method which will be automatically called after the slot is successfully extracted using your defined slot mappings.

Assuming your email slot is called `email` your validate method name should be `validate_email` and would look like this:

```
def validate_email(
    self,
    value: Text,
    dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
    tracker: Tracker,
    domain: Dict[Text, Any],
) -> Dict[Text, Any]:
    """Validate email value."""

    # Your regex  validation logic...
```

Check this [link](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/40cfc1ffa788ddf3beb59f06c0be5dc0b63d185f/examples/formbot/actions/actions.py#L72) to check an example of what you should return inside a `validate_{slot_name}` method.